# Sending message with c# SmtpClient

Tags: c#, smtp, mailkit

I made 2 implementations of the same mail sending:

```
//MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient smtp;
var message = new MimeMessage();

message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test sender", "sender@domain.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test Recipiment", "recipient@domain.com"));
message.Subject = "My subject";         
message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = "my body"
};
smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
smtp.Connect("mail.domain.com","25",false);
smtp.Authenticate("sender", "MyPassword");

smtp.Send(message);
smtp.Disconnect(true);
smtp.Dispose();

//System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com","25");
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

MailAddress fromMailAdd;
try
{
    fromMailAdd = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com");
}
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    From = fromMailAdd,
    IsBodyHtml = false,
    Body = "my body",
    Subject = "My subject",
};
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@domain.com"));

smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender", "MyPassword");
smpt.Send(mailMessage);
```

The MailKit implementation is working the System.Net.Mail is not working. It gets `"Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: authentication is required"`

I looked at the code of the MailKit SmtpClient and its authentication does the following:

```
    var saslUri = new Uri ($"smtp://{uri.Host}");
    AuthenticationException authException = null;
    SmtpResponse response;
    SaslMechanism sasl;
    bool tried = false;
    string challenge;
    string command;

    foreach (var authmech in SaslMechanism.AuthMechanismRank) {
        if (!AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains (authmech))
            continue;

        if ((sasl = SaslMechanism.Create (authmech, saslUri, encoding, credentials)) == null)
            continue;

        tried = true;

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();

        // send an initial challenge if the mechanism supports it
        if (sasl.SupportsInitialResponse) {
            challenge = sasl.Challenge (null);
            command = string.Format ("AUTH {0} {1}", authmech, challenge);
        } else {
            command = string.Format ("AUTH {0}", authmech);
        }

        response = await SendCommandAsync (command, doAsync, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait (false);

        if (response.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.AuthenticationMechanismTooWeak)
            continue;

        SaslException saslException = null;

        try {
            while (!sasl.IsAuthenticated) {
                if (response.StatusCode != SmtpStatusCode.AuthenticationChallenge)
                    break;

                challenge = sasl.Challenge (response.Response);
                response = await SendCommandAsync (challenge, doAsync, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait (false);
            }

            saslException = null;
        } catch (SaslException ex) {
            // reset the authentication state
            response = await SendCommandAsync (string.Empty, doAsync, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait (false);
            saslException = ex;
        }

        if (response.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.AuthenticationSuccessful) {
            if (sasl.NegotiatedSecurityLayer)
                await EhloAsync (doAsync, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait (false);
            authenticated = true;
            OnAuthenticated (response.Response);
            return;
        }

        var message = string.Format ("{0}: {1}", (int) response.StatusCode, response.Response);
        Exception inner;

        if (saslException != null)
            inner = new SmtpCommandException (SmtpErrorCode.UnexpectedStatusCode, response.StatusCode, response.Response, saslException);
        else
            inner = new SmtpCommandException (SmtpErrorCode.UnexpectedStatusCode, response.StatusCode, response.Response);

        authException = new AuthenticationException (message, inner);
    }

    if (tried)
        throw authException ?? new AuthenticationException ();

    throw new NotSupportedException ("No compatible authentication mechanisms found.");
```

the credentials is the same NetworkCredentials class as the one used in the .Net Mail client

is it possible to get the .net Mail client to do the same type of authentication?

EDIT:
It is not possible to change something on the mail server itself

Comment: Go to the mail server website and find out the proper settings for using smtp.  You are using : "mail.domain.com","25" Port 25 is the non secure port for SMTP.  Most mail server refuse to use port 25.

Comment: The working implementation in the sample above is also using port 25 and I have no more information on the mail server and can not get any

Comment: The From address and the user has to be from same email account.

Comment: yes they are in both samples

Comment: One is sender the other myUser.  Not the same.

Comment: they are I just didn't put the realistic username or password here. I updated the sample

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the http/smtp  messages between MailKit and Net.  They should be the same.  Look at the headers in the message.

Comment: will try that and report back

Comment: It's possible that System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient does not support any of the authentication mechanisms supported by the SMTP server while MailKit does.